# Google fit data in one device is not accessible in another device with same account

Tags: android, google-fit

I am working with Google Fit [History](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history) API and I am able to insert and read data. While testing in multiple devices logged in with the same account, I see that data inserted in device 1 is not available for reading in device 2. Can anyone tell why is it this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How long did you wait.  Synch has been seen to take potentially 24+ hours unless you do stuff to try and force it.

Comment: I have tried doing force sync in Settings->Users & accounts->Google account and also I have waited for 24+ hours. But no luck